# App module not installing, when android instant app is build

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have created an android instant app, and it was able to run on the device successfully, the src folders are generated in feature module, when I try to build and install app module, it is showing mainactivity not found, as src files are in feature module. Any suggestion?

app/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lifeclock.nishanths.lifeclock.app" />
```

base/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lifeclock.nishanths.lifeclock">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"/>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="aia-compat-api-min-version"
            android:value="1" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

feature/AndroidManifest.xml has all the activities listed.

Comment: Got a solution for this, just updated application id. By default app id has .app extension and after removing that from app/build.gradle installable app is build and running.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that. If you go to your `app` manifest and select the sub-tab "Merged Manifest", does it show a DEFAULT activity there? What version of studio are you using?